# Firebase Authentication console is not showing new users added

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I implemented a simple login for users in my Android app with email/password. When I sign up a user their info would almost instantly show up on the Firebase console. This no longer happens and I'm not able to delete users via the console. It works completely fine on the iOS side, which uses the same Firebase project.

Here is my code for creating a user.

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "User was successfully created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sendEmailVerification();
                            EmailConfirmationFragment fragment = new EmailConfirmationFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.registration_root, fragment)
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error detected. " + task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think anything changed in the Firebase console to cause that. Some troubleshooting steps 1) Is your user is actually registered? 2) Are you looking at the same project in the console? 3) Do you have any extensions in the browser that may be blocking content? If so, please enable all such plugins, try in incognito window, or in a different browser. If none of these steps works, it might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: How would I confirm the users are actually being registered? Another thing I forgot to mention, I'm unable to sign in any users that I am able to view via the console. It's almost as if my app's functionality is isolated from Firebase yet the user's I create still receive verification emails and are able to reset passwords.

Comment: It really sounds like you're looking at a different project in your console than what your code is talking to. You might want to double check the project Id in your `google-services.json` file against what you have in the console.

Comment: They both have the same project_id. My colleague is also having the same problem. The thing is it worked for a while and then stopped.

Comment: Interesting. Your code looks fine, so I doubt we can do much about it here. It might be a good idea to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. Maybe they can see something misconfigured about your project.

Comment: Done and done. Thank you for all your input!

Answer (score -1):

First, check your "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```